# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.NewProfile.service.personneService' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring Boot and I'm getting the following error when writing a file upload API

**Description:**

Field personneservice in com.example.NewProfile.controller.clientController required a bean of type 'com.example.NewProfile.service.personneService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.NewProfile.service.personneService' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1

**service interface:**

```
package com.example.NewProfile.service;

import com.example.NewProfile.model.personne;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
@Service
public interface personneService {
    personne createPersonne(personne person1);

    List<personne> getPersonne();


    personne getPersonneById(long id);
    void deletePersonne(long id);

    personne updatePersonne(personne person1,long id);


}
```

**Service class IMPL :**

```
package com.example.NewProfile.service;

import com.example.NewProfile.model.personne;
import com.example.NewProfile.repository.personneRepository;

import java.util.List;

public class personneServiceImlp implements personneService{
    private final personneRepository personRepository;

    public personneServiceImlp(personneRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public personne createPersonne(personne person1) {
        return personRepository.save(person1);
    }

    @Override
    public List<personne> getPersonne() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public personne getPersonneById(long id) {
        return personRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void deletePersonne(long id) {
        personRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public personne updatePersonne(personne person1, long id) {
        personne person2 = personRepository.findById(id).get();
        person2.setNom(person1.getNom());
        person2.setPrenom(person1.getPrenom());
        person2.setDate_naissance(person1.getDate_naissance());
        return personRepository.save(person2);
    }
}
```

**Contoller class:**

```
package com.example.NewProfile.controller;


import com.example.NewProfile.model.personne;
import com.example.NewProfile.service.personneService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/personne")
public class clientController {

    @Autowired
    private personneService personneservice;

    @PostMapping
    public personne createpersonne(@RequestBody personne person){
        personne person1 = personneservice.createPersonne(person);
        return person1;
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<personne> getPersons(){
        return personneservice.getPersonne();
    }

    //update persons
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public personne updatePersonById(@RequestBody personne person , @PathVariable("id") long id){
        return personneservice.updatePersonne(person,id);
    }

    //Delete Person by id
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String deletePerson(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        personneservice.deletePersonne(id);
        return "person is successfully deleted";
    }

    //Get Person by id
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public personne getPersonById(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        return personneservice.getPersonneById(id);
    }

}
```

**model :**

```
package com.example.NewProfile.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.sql.Date;
@Entity
public class personne {
    @Id
    private  long id;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private Date date_naissance;


    public personne() {

    }
    public personne(long id, String nom, String prenom, Date date_naissance){
        this.id=id;
        this.nom=nom;
        this.prenom=prenom;
        this.date_naissance=date_naissance;

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public Date getDate_naissance() {
        return date_naissance;
    }

    public void setDate_naissance(Date date_naissance) {
        this.date_naissance = date_naissance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the `@Service` annotation on `personneServiceImlp`, and please find out what the standard Java naming conventions are and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Move @Service from PersonneService to PersonneServiceImpl.
(just a remark: try to respect java naming rules (Upper cases and lower ones)